# Referencing an x64 dll file works in C# but does not work in F#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, f#, vtk

I have created two brand new solutions using the latest VS 2010:

- C# console application
- F# console application

I have referenced two x64 dll files: `Kitware.VTK.dll` and `Kitware.mummy.Runtime.dll`
(can be downloaded here: http://www.kitware.com/products/avdownload.php )

The C# VS 2010 finds the namespace when I write `using Kitware`.
The F# VS 2010 does not find the namespace when I write `open Kitware`.

The x86 version works fine in F#. Any idea why is that and how to make the Kitware x64 work in F#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to the bug described here:

[F# project references not working when targeting x64 platform in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536945/f-project-references-not-working-when-targeting-x64-platform-in-visual-studio-20)

They say it will be fixed in the next release of VS.

be well
-h-

Comment: It looks like that bug is in VS 2010 beta 1, and has since been fixed.

Comment: Wait, I take that back. It was at least still present in the beta of the Service Pack for VS 2010.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug that I believe is present in all of the shipped versions of the product, unfortunately.

Comment: I will take that as a correct answer because I have no clue what else could cause it. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

F# console applications default to targeting x86 rather than Any CPU. If you haven't changed that, then the F# project won't work with an x64 library.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I have added x64 target to the console application.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a fix for that. It requires manually editing your fsproj file.

Add this after the `<PropertyGroup>` items and before the first `<Import>`.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
    <!--
    Assembly resolution using msbuild is broken for the x64 platform in F# 2.0.
    See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588317/f-project-references-not-working-when-targeting-x64-platform-in-visual-studio-2010
    We use simple resolution with a hard-coded list of paths to look for the dlls instead.
    -->
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <OtherFlags>--simpleresolution</OtherFlags>
    <ReferencePath>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727</ReferencePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Note that `OtherFlags` is overwritten, which was OK for me as it was empty. If it's used, you should probably append to the variable instead.
It would be nice to use `Microsoft.Build.Tasks` for the list of paths, instead of using a hard-coded list, but I haven't been able to get that to work.