# Referencing an executable from F#

Tags: f#, 64-bit, f#-interactive

I've used F# to do some quick data-analysis using datastructures from another project.  To do so, it needs access to this project; i.e. it needs an assembly reference - but the project is an executable.

I've tried this in F# interactive, and it almost works*; I can `#I` the appropriate path and `#r` the executable and a few support dll's - but I can't actually use em.  And whatever I do, I can't get the reference into a compiled F# program:  VS lets me add a reference just fine, and the appropriate compiler option `-r:X:full\path\here.exe` is correctly generated by the project, but none of the datastructures are present and the compiler complains of non-existent namespaces; it's as if the reference didn't exist.  The application is 64-bit, which may be relevant.  64-bit dll's work fine.

(*) after setting fsi.exe to run in 64-bit mode it thinks it can load it, but actually using it returns FS0193: internal error.

How can I reference a managed 64-bit executable from an F# project?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6661833/162396

Comment: Which in turn refers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536945 and that does look related.  What's odd is that dll's seem to work; so this doesn't sound quite identical.  Maybe they fixed it for dll's?  In any case, setting the other project to Any CPU is a fine work-around, even though that's certainly the wrong thing to do in general.

Comment: Can you reference it from c#?

Comment: Sure - this seems to be some bug in fsi/fsc whereby it can't read the headers(?) of a 64-bit marked assembly.  The exact same code also in 64-bit works fine marked as Any CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To others with this same issue: as a workaround, I'm now compiling the executable as Any CPU (which will be executed in 64-bit mode, so behaves the same).  This allows FSI and the compiler to reference it.  Based on the questions referenced in the comments, this seems to be a known bug that will hopefully be fixed some day.